# Why doesn't my conversion from Class to Constructor function work?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

I was attempting to convert a piece of code from Class to Constructor function for adaption. Although there was no indication of bugs in the console, the pie does not appear in live preview at all.

Basically, I swapped class Slice and class Piechart to the below.

```
'use strict';

function Slice(lbl, val, strt, fll) {
        this.label = lbl;
        this.value = constrain(val, 0.0, 1.0);
        this.start = constrain(strt, 0.0, TWO_PI);
        var valAngle = map(this.value, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, TWO_PI);
        this.middle = this.start + valAngle * 0.5;
        this.stop = this.start + valAngle;
        this.fillFocus = color(fll, 99, 99, 255);
        this.fillNoFocus = color(fll, 89, 49, 189);
        this.fill = this.fillNoFocus;
        this.hasFocus = false;
        this.labelInset = 0.667;

    this.toString = function() {
        return this.label + ": " + (this.value * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
    };

    this.draw = function(cx, cy, radius) {
        if (this.hasFocus) {
            this.fill = lerpColor(this.fill,
                    this.fillFocus,
                    Slice.focusFadeIn);
        } else {
            this.fill = lerpColor(this.fill,
                    this.fillNoFocus,
                    Slice.focusFadeOut);
        }

        fill(this.fill);
        arc(cx, cy, radius, radius,
            this.start, this.stop);
    };

    this.showLabel = function(cx, cy, radius) {
        var x = cx + cos(this.middle) * radius * this.labelInset;
        var y = cy + sin(this.middle) * radius * this.labelInset;
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        text(this, x, y);
        fill(0, 0, 99);
        text(this, x - 1, y - 1);
    };

    this.hover = function(angle) {
        angle = angle < 0 ? angle + TWO_PI : angle;
        return angle > this.start && angle < this.stop;
    };
}
```

Here is the [code](https://codepen.io/behreajj/pen/BRePoo) to be adapted.

Edit: I am an absolute beginner at coding who is trying out different mini tutorial projects, the coding style I have above is based on the teachings of a beginner lesson to Javascript.

Comment: Please don't tag-spam.  This is not a `[java]` question.

Comment: I don't see any modern JS `class` code in your post. You're showing an at this point truly ancient single-function-based pattern (not even a constructor function with a prototype assignment, which itself is already an outdated pattern).

Comment: the easiest way to achieve this is to use `https://babeljs.io/repl` - paste the `class` code in there, and select the appropriate options - and check the code produced - your code is different to what babel produces, but not significantly

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That seems to be the point of the question.

Comment: It does, but since it's a question of "how do I turn X into Y", a good post should contain both: show what you have, and show what you (wanted to) turn it into, with the code if you're automating the process, or textual description of your approach if it's a manual procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I think conversion is not correct Please replace your js with following code.

```
'use strict';

function _createForOfIteratorHelperLoose(o, allowArrayLike) { var it = typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && o[Symbol.iterator] || o["@@iterator"]; if (it) return (it = it.call(o)).next.bind(it); if (Array.isArray(o) || (it = _unsupportedIterableToArray(o)) || allowArrayLike && o && typeof o.length === "number") { if (it) o = it; var i = 0; return function () { if (i >= o.length) return { done: true }; return { done: false, value: o[i++] }; }; } throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance.\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method."); }

function _unsupportedIterableToArray(o, minLen) { if (!o) return; if (typeof o === "string") return _arrayLikeToArray(o, minLen); var n = Object.prototype.toString.call(o).slice(8, -1); if (n === "Object" && o.constructor) n = o.constructor.name; if (n === "Map" || n === "Set") return Array.from(o); if (n === "Arguments" || /^(?:Ui|I)nt(?:8|16|32)(?:Clamped)?Array$/.test(n)) return _arrayLikeToArray(o, minLen); }

function _arrayLikeToArray(arr, len) { if (len == null || len > arr.length) len = arr.length; for (var i = 0, arr2 = new Array(len); i < len; i++) { arr2[i] = arr[i]; } return arr2; }

var Slice = /*#__PURE__*/function () {
  function Slice(lbl, val, strt, fll) {
    this.label = lbl;
    this.value = constrain(val, 0.0, 1.0);
    this.start = constrain(strt, 0.0, TWO_PI);
    var valAngle = map(this.value, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, TWO_PI);
    this.middle = this.start + valAngle * 0.5;
    this.stop = this.start + valAngle;
    this.fillFocus = color(fll, 99, 99, 255);
    this.fillNoFocus = color(fll, 89, 49, 189);
    this.fill = this.fillNoFocus;
    this.hasFocus = false;
    this.labelInset = 0.667;
  }

  var _proto = Slice.prototype;

  _proto.toString = function toString() {
    return this.label + ": " + (this.value * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
  };

  _proto.draw = function draw(cx, cy, radius) {
    if (this.hasFocus) {
      this.fill = lerpColor(this.fill, this.fillFocus, Slice.focusFadeIn);
    } else {
      this.fill = lerpColor(this.fill, this.fillNoFocus, Slice.focusFadeOut);
    }

    fill(this.fill);
    arc(cx, cy, radius, radius, this.start, this.stop);
  };

  _proto.showLabel = function showLabel(cx, cy, radius) {
    var x = cx + cos(this.middle) * radius * this.labelInset;
    var y = cy + sin(this.middle) * radius * this.labelInset;
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    text(this, x, y);
    fill(0, 0, 99);
    text(this, x - 1, y - 1);
  } // atan2 returns a value in the range of -PI to PI.
  // If the angle is less than 0 radians, we can fix the
  // problem by adding TWO_PI to it.
  ;

  _proto.hover = function hover(angle) {
    angle = angle < 0 ? angle + TWO_PI : angle;
    return angle > this.start && angle < this.stop;
  };

  return Slice;
}();

Slice.focusFadeIn = 0.05;
Slice.focusFadeOut = 0.025;

var PieChart = /*#__PURE__*/function () {
  function PieChart(x, y, rad, name, data) {
    this.scale(x, y, rad);
    this.hasFocus = false;
    this.name = name; // Assumes data is an ES6 map.
    // Sum the values in the data so as to
    // normalize them to a percent.

    var sum = 0;
    var itr = data.entries();

    for (var _iterator = _createForOfIteratorHelperLoose(data.values()), _step; !(_step = _iterator()).done;) {
      var value = _step.value;
      sum += value;
      console.log(value);
    }

    sum = sum <= 1 ? 1 : sum;
    console.log("sum: ", sum);
    this.slices = [];
    var i = 0;

    for (var _iterator2 = _createForOfIteratorHelperLoose(data.entries()), _step2; !(_step2 = _iterator2()).done;) {
      var _step2$value = _step2.value,
          key = _step2$value[0],
          value = _step2$value[1];
      this.slices.push(new Slice(key, isNaN(value) ? 0 : value / sum, i === 0 ? 0 : this.slices[i - 1].stop, i / data.size * 360));
      i++;
    }
  }

  var _proto2 = PieChart.prototype;

  _proto2.draw = function draw() {
    push();
    noStroke();
    ellipseMode(RADIUS);
    textSize(16);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);

    for (var i = 0, size = this.slices.length; i < size; ++i) {
      this.slices[i].draw(this.x, this.y, this.radius);
    }

    if (this.hasFocus) {
      var y = this.y + this.radius + 16;
      fill(0, 0, 0);
      text(this.name, this.x, y);
      fill(0, 0, 99);
      text(this.name, this.x - 1, y - 1);
    }

    pop();
    this.hover(mouseX, mouseY);
  };

  _proto2.hover = function hover(x, y) {
    if (dist(x, y, this.x, this.y) < this.radius) {
      this.hasFocus = true;

      for (var i = 0, size = this.slices.length; i < size; ++i) {
        var a = atan2(y - this.y, x - this.x);

        if (this.slices[i].hover(a)) {
          this.slices[i].hasFocus = true;
          this.slices[i].showLabel(this.x, this.y, this.radius);
        } else {
          this.slices[i].hasFocus = false;
        }
      }
    } else {
      this.hasFocus = false;

      for (var i = 0, size = this.slices.length; i < size; ++i) {
        this.slices[i].hasFocus = false;
      }
    }
  };

  _proto2.scale = function scale(x, y, rad) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = rad;
  };

  return PieChart;
}();

var cnvs = null;
var data = new Map();
var pie = null;

function setup() {
  cnvs = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  pixelDensity(displayDensity());
  smooth();
  colorMode(HSB, 359, 99, 99);
  data.set('Alpha', random(1, 50));
  data.set('Bravo', random(1, 50));
  data.set('Charlie', random(1, 50));
  data.set('Delta', random(1, 50));
  data.set('Echo', random(1, 50));
  data.set('Foxtrot', random(1, 50));
  pie = new PieChart(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, min(width, height) * 0.333, "Example", data);
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 0, 0);
  pie.draw();
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  pie.scale(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, min(width, height) * 0.333);
}
```

Here is a working [sample](https://codepen.io/negirox/pen/RwVezdw).